# How can I put all lines in textView to tableView Cell?

Tags: ios, uitableview, textview, cell

In my app when clicking on a `cell` of `tableView` it segues to a `textView`. I save the `textView.text` in Firebase and can show up in tableView Cell. Now one problem, if text in textView is more than one line (clicking `return` when typing), in Firebase it saves as for example, ABC\nDEF\nGHI, when I retrieve data from Firebase, and add it to my text `array`, after printing, there is one item, three lines, like

```
[ABC
 DEF
 GHI]
```

When I put it in `tableView cell`, it only shows ABC. How can I put all text in the cell? If Firebase can output like ABC DEF GHI in one line and in the `array` it is like [ABC DEF GHI] in one line, so everything should show up in the `cell`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how to combine these strings:

```
let str = "ABC\nDEF\nGHI"
let components = str.componentsSeparatedByString("\n")
let combinedStr = components.joinWithSeparator("")
```

Comment: It works vey well! Thank you and have a great weekend!

Answer (score 0):

Your cell contains a UILabel that holds the text. This should work even if you're using one of the default `textLabel` or `detailTextLabel` property.

```
cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0
```

You can replace `textLabel` with the name of the label you're using when configuring the cell.

You can also se the lineBreakMode to wrap:

```
cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakMode.ByWordWrapping
```

Comment: Thanks. I put cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 0 in code and the cell changes to ABC... , DEF and GHI still didn't show.  And UILineBreakModeWordWrap is unresolved identifier, I cannot add it.

Comment: @iosfan Do you want to see multiple lines under each other, or a single long line?

Comment: Multiple lines or single long line both are ok, as long as all text can show up in one cell.